# Garbarge collector order

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, dispose

I know the .Net garbage collector cannot guarantee any order when destroying objects but I am really suprised of the following behaviour:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication2 {
class Program {

    class A {
        public A() { i = 1; }
        private int i;

        // TODO: override a finalizer only if Dispose(bool disposing) above has code to free unmanaged resources.
        ~A() {
            // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
            Console.WriteLine("Disposed A");
        }
    }

    class B {
        static int p = 0;
        public B(A a) {
            this.a = a;
            j = p++;
        }

        ~B() {
            Console.WriteLine("Disposed " + j.ToString());
        }

        private int j;
        private A a;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        A a_obj = new A();
        List<B> bs = new List<B>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            B b = new B(a_obj);
            bs.Add(b);
        }
    }
}
}
```

This execution has the following (possible) output:

Disposed 9

Disposed 2

Disposed 1

Disposed 0

Disposed A

Disposed 8

Disposed 7

Disposed 6

Disposed 5

Disposed 4

Disposed 3

I can understand that the order of B objects is not deterministic but
how is possible that the garbage collector destroys a_obj, if there are still some B objects that have a reference to a_obj and has not been destroyed still?

Comment: GC in concurrent mode runs in a separate thread, maybe it's simply a delay in writing to the console? Is the order consistent?

Comment: It *has* to do that; otherwise any two garbage objects could keep each-other alive forever by referencing each-other; basically, once objects are not *rooted* (reachable by real code), then they are garbage; at that point, any references **inside** the garbage are **irrelevant** and ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET garbage collector does not use reference counting, so it doesn't matter how many references to `a_obj` there is. What matters is what objects are reachable from roots (like static variables). In your case, all objects (`A` and all `B`s) become unreachable from root at the same time and so are all eligible to garbage collection, their mutual references do not matter. If `A` and `B` are both unreachable and will be collected in the same cycle, why bother about order in which this will happen? Also if order was dependent on which object references which - think about how it would then collect objects that have mutual references to each other?

Here is also a quote from [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize(v=vs.110).aspx) which fits your situation exactly:

> The finalizers of two objects are not guaranteed to run in any
>   specific order, even if one object refers to the other. That is, if
>   Object A has a reference to Object B and both have finalizers, Object
>   B might have already been finalized when the finalizer of Object A
>   starts.

Also note that first all finalizers will run and only then objects will be really dead and memory taken by them might be reused (you can even ressurect object in finalizer via `GC.ReRegisterForFinalize`). So you can access `A` from `B`'s finalizer, even though `A`'s finalizer might have already been run at this point. Obviously you should avoid doing this anyway.

Comment: it makes sense. How can I then deal with this problem?

Comment: Which problem exactly? I don't see any problem here.

Answer (score 1):

If none of the elements that reference `a_obj` are referenced, the GC can collect it, because the application root has no way of obtaining a reference to it again.

Here is the relevant part of [a good tutorial on C# object lifecycle](http://mr-ponna.com/Article/21/Understanding-Object-Lifetime/)

During a garbage collection process, the runtime will investigate objects on the managed heap to determine whether they are still reachable (rooted) by the application. To do so, the **CLR will build an object graph**, which represents each reachable object on the heap. Object graphs are used to document all reachable objects. 
[...]
**Once the graph has been constructed, unreachable objects are marked as garbage.**

Answer (score 0):

The output is produced when process is being shut down, at this point GC is cleaning whole memory allocated during process, references between objects do not affect the order of cleaning.